# Is there a faster way to do @property , @synthesize and release a class variable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I know `@synthesize` has already reduced lot of my work of writing getters and setters. But one common procedure I often have to use are these 4 steps for example

1. `SomeView *abc;`
2. `@property(nonatomic,retain)SomeView *abc;`
3. `@synthesize abc;`
4. `[abc release];`

Has someone come up with any idea where I write `SomeView *abc`; in `.h` and steps 2,3,4 are generated automatically?

Comment: Frankly, I don't think it can get much better than that! It's quite convenient.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you don't actually need step 1 -- `@synthesize abc;` takes care of that for you. Or what I do is `@syntheisze abc = _abc;` so that the property doesn't get confused with the instance variable.

Comment: Wish XCode would provide a shortcut for this; if you have tons of variables to create with the similar pattern, this gets a bit irritating

Comment: Don't use single leading underscores on ivar names.  That's an internal coding convention at Apple.

Comment: @NSResponder - It's recommended that you don't do this for methods, but there doesn't seem to be a restriction on leading underscores for iVar names.

Comment: ARC now takes care of this. You just do step 2 and all the rest happens for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's an `IBOutlet`, Xcode will write all that code for you when you create the variable using IB. You just drag from the object you want to reference in the interface editor to the location in the header file where you want the property declaration, fill out a form, and hit OK.

As others have mentioned, you can skip declaring the backing ivar in favor of having the `@synthesize` generate it for you.

You can skip the `@synthesize` by using the appropriate compiler flags. Search the web for something like "default @synthesize".

One way to skip `-dealloc` is to dangle the objects off your main object using the Obj-C associated object API. Retained associated objects will be released when the object they are associated with is released.

And then there's Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), which eliminates `-dealloc` much more cleanly and definitively.

Comment: automatic @synthesize isn't available yet.

Comment: latter parts are new to me, thank you for the info, will look into this.. is it advisable to use 1) skipping of @synthesize by using appropriate compiler flags and 2) skip -dealloc by association / ARC? What I mean is do developers actually use and prefer this over the usual?

Comment: Apparently, support for default `@synthesize` was added and then just as quickly removed. I expect the feature will be widely used whenever it is restored. Skipping `-dealloc` by way of association is unusual but doable. Skipping it by way of ARC will become SOP once Apple releases a version of Xcode that bundles a compiler that supports ARC.

Answer (score 5):

Skip step one, it is not necessary, the @synthesize will create the ivar.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a lot of help, but one thing I do is move dealloc to the top of the implementation, ahead of other methods.  The @synthesize statements are right above that, so you can put in the @synthesize and the release often without having to scroll.  It's not really a big time-saver when coding, but it does help you keep the two sections in sync, and that's a time-saver when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad thing to wish for. And it's done for you already in some cases:

In Xcode 4's Interface Builder when you drag an element onto it's file's owner's .h file it does this 1-4 for you, and even sets it to nil in `viewDidUnload` for you.

1. Not needed with the modern runtime.
2. Still need to do this.
3. Doing away with this was talked about in the WWDC10 (113 and 144) sessions, but the release notes say that this hasn't happened yet.
4. Use ARC, and you don't need this.

That's 2 of the 4 that you don't need to do, and one that they are working on removing. So it's not all there yet - but it is getting easier.